# How to do like this animation in blender in an easy way

Tags: animation, modifiers

How do I do the animation in the image

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a descriptive title that reflects the content of the question, also state what you have tried and where it failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with bones:

- Create a bone, subdivide it:

[image]

- In *Pose* mode, give the second bone a *Transformation* constraint, choose the first bone as *Target*, set it so that it inverts the rotation of the first bone:

[image]

- Activate the *Copy Attibutes* addon, select bone 3 and 4, select bone 2 at last, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> in order to copy the constraint. For bone 3 invert the rotation direction (here -360/360° instead of 360/-360°), rotate the first bone, the other ones should follow. Parent the first bone to a root bone if necessary:

[image]